# Scala Await on Future with request.onComplete

Tags: scala, playframework, async-await

In my REST-GET Route I have to verify a Firebase User-Token using an GRPC-Server, the server than returns me the UserID which I can use to get the User out of my Database and return it via HTTP.

So because I have a a-sync operation here, I decided to create a Future for the gRPC request and will use *Await* before I start my SQL queries.
The problem is: In my Future I have this 'reply.onComplete' and *Await* will not wait for this to complete. I understand why, but I don't know how I can wait for the *onComplete* statement to finish.

```
 def login(token: String) = Action { _ =>   
    var uid="START_VALUE"
    val f = Future {
      implicit val sys = ActorSystem("ActorName")
      implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
      implicit val ec = sys.dispatcher

      val client = UserServiceClient(GrpcClientSettings.fromConfig("user.UserService"))
      val reply = client.verifyUser(UserToken(token))
      reply.onComplete {
        case Success(msg: UserId) => uid=msg.uid.toString()
        case Failure(exception) => InternalServerError(exception.toString())
        case _ => InternalServerError("Unknown ERROR on verifyUser") 
      }

    }   
    Await.ready(f, Duration.Inf)
    println(uid)
    //SQL GET USER STUFF
    //Ok(User)
```

So the output is always *START_VALUE*
I tried using two Futures and use *Await* on the *f2*

```
  val f = Future {
      implicit val sys = ActorSystem("SmartMarkt")
      implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
      implicit val ec = sys.dispatcher     
      val client = UserServiceClient(GrpcClientSettings.fromConfig("user.UserService"))
      val reply = client.verifyUser(UserToken(token))
    }     
    val f2 = f andThen { 
        case Success(msg: UserId) => uid=msg.uid.toString()
        case Failure(exception) => InternalServerError(exception.toString())
        case _ => InternalServerError("Unknown ERROR on verifyUser") 

    }
```

But than I get
`scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : user.UserId
 required: Unitbloop`
for `case Success(msg: UserId) => uid=msg.uid.toString()`

Comment: There is "some" code smell there. Avoid await future, rather compose with it (e.g. using `Action.async`), avoid creating heavyweight actor system, execution context or materializer, but resolve such resources from the context (class level, implicit scope, ...)

Comment: I looked at this [example](http://carminedimascio.com/2015/09/asynchronous-programming-with-async-await-and-the-scala-play-framework/) for Action.async. Maybe I´m wrong, but my problem, that i have/want to wait for the response not only wait for completing the request, is still the same, or?

Comment: No, you should never await a Future, at least in Play actions

Comment: But i have too (or not?). I can make my login `def login(token: String) = Action.async` and extract the grpc request and sql request in own functions. Than, in my `login` I would  do something like `var id= verifyUser(token)` and *after that* `user= getUser(id) Ok(user)`  But how do i do that, without Await?

Comment: You should first understand how to compose and work with `Future` (many tutorial around the Web)